# Where can I find a list of icon images for the dojo toolkit dijit widgets?

Tags: javascript, css, widget, dojo

Simple question I guess, but despite some googling I'm no closer to finding an answer. Does anyone know where to find a list of the icons available in the Dojo toolkit?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best place to look at would be [Dojo Toolkit nightly icon directory](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/icons/). Here you can view the CSS classes that correspond to all available icon styles, and if you [go to the images directory](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/icons/images/) you can actually see the icon sprites. Unfortunately this isn't as simple as a *Class Name* -> *Icon Image* mapping, but all the CSS class names are listed in the same order as the sprite images, left to right.

To quickly scan, know that the `commonIcons.css` file break down the classes in this order:

1. Icon Class
2. IE6 Icon Class (8 bit)
3. Disabled Icon Class
4. Setting background positions to their respective places on the sprite image

The `editorIcons.css` class simply lists all class names.

I was able to find the [Dijit Editor icons](http://amagard.x10.mx/dojo_icon_classes.html) in an easier to read list, however, this is not maintained by Dojo like the site above and will not necessarily keep up to date.

Comment: I threw together this quick [Dojo Icon CSS Class List](http://tando.com.au/dojo-icon-css-class-list/) just as an up-to-date reference for myself. Thought it might come in handy for someone else out there.