# Arrow icons implementation using dojo

Tags: javascript, graphics, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

Need to implement arrow icons in the webpage...

Currently we are using these classes for displaying icons with some significant operations on click.

```
            iconClass : "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconUnlink",
            iconClass : "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconInsertTable",
            iconClass : "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconDelete",
```

Are there any similar classes for right and left arrows implementation ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[They are](http://www.javaexperience.com/list-of-button-icons-in-dojo/).
[Answered in a related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887440/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-icon-images-for-the-dojo-toolkit-dijit-widgets)

Comment: Thanks xyu.....One more help required

.dijitEditorRtl .dijitEditorIcon {
 background-image: url('images/editorIconsEnabled_rtl.png'); 
}

How to access this kind a class in JavaScript 
iconClass : "dijitEditorRtl dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconTabIndent", 
??

Comment: Please define "access". Get an elements icon class?

Comment: .dijitEditorIcon {
       background-image: url('../dojoroot/dijit/icons/images/editorIconsEnabled.png');
       }


Usage --  iconClass : "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconTabIndent", 
              To get an right arrow  -SUCCESS  
   


.dijitEditorRtl .dijitEditorIcon {
   background-image: url('../dojoroot/dijit/icons/images/editorIconsEnabled_rtl.png'); 
}


Usage ---iconClass : "dijitEditorRtl dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconTabIndent",

             To get an left arrow  -FAILURE

Comment: I don't think that the rtl classes can be applied directly. However the `dijitEditorIconOutdent` class contains a left arrow. See [here](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/editor/test_Editor.html) and [here](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/editor/test_ToggleDir_rtl.html) to see how the classes are applied.