# Plus sign and Minus sign in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, icons

I want to replace my data-dojo-attach-point="incrementButton" and data-dojo-attach-point="decrementButton" (arrow icons), with plus and minus icons Instead.

But I can't find any plus and minus icons. Does It exist In the dojo package?

Comment: Here you can find some interesting links to dojo icons http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887440/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-icon-images-for-the-dojo-toolkit-dijit-widgets. But I think you have to find or create or own icons for plus and minus.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such iconClass in the dojo. You can write your own iconClass using css.

```
<div .... iconClass='myIconClass'>

.myIconClass {
    background:url(".....");
}
```